# calling inner variable of a function

Tags: javascript, function

Why is it that I have to use a new instance of a function in order to get an inner variable, but I can't use the function itself,

why this works

```
function bla(){this.a = 1}
b = new bla
alert (b.a)
```

and this doesn't

```
function bla(){this.a = 1}
alert (bla.a)
```

?

Comment: The `bla` function is called as a constructor which makes it a constructor function. Constructor functions return new instances. The line `this.a = 1` assigns a `a` property to a new instance. If you don't call the constructor once, there are no instances, ergo, there is no `a` property. Note that `a` is **not** an "inner variable of the function", but a property of the instances returned by the constructor. And again, if there are no instances, there is no `a` property.

Comment: .. of course, you can create one without running the constructor function, `var b = function bla() { this.a = 1; };  b.a = 5;`  Oooh, the mystery continues... ;)

Comment: @Marc That won't work. The `this` keyword references the global object, not the `b` function. And still, you **do have** to call the function at least once in order for that assignment to execute.

Comment: @Sime: I think you missed my snarkiness at the confusion of scope that constructors can bring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have to call the function in order for the variable to be defined.

If you want to do what you're talking about, you can use an *object literal*

```
var bla = 
{
  a: 1,

  displayA: function() {
    alert(bla.a);
  }
};

alert(bla.a); // Displays 1
bla.displayA(); // Displays 1
```

Comment: dont ever linebreak before an opening curly brace in javascript. semicolon insertion will screw you over on certain constructs (eg. `` return {value: 42}`` will _not_ return the object if you move the opening curly brace on the next line)

Comment: I tried your example, and you're right, "return" is apparently a special case in that a new line is also viewed as a end of statement (something I didn't know). Otherwise, javascript code snippets are segmented using curly braces, commas, and semi-colons; new lines affect nothing. It's just a matter of semantics, it goes to the age old debate of whether to go new-line with starting curly braces, or same-line. I like new-line, because I believe it looks cleaner, but everyone can have their own preference.

Comment: This is not correct. new lines in javascript do affect something: semicolon insertion. If an expression/statement is syntactically correct at the point of a newline, javascript will insert a semicolon. Since ``return`` is a valid statement, a semicolon will be inserted. This can produce terrible and hard to trace bugs. Imagine what happens if you accidentally forget the equal sign after ``bla`` in your code snippet...

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new instance of the object. In this case, the first one works because you declare

```
b = new bla
```

Just a side tip, you should have wrote it more like this to prevent possible errors...

```
function bla(){this.a = 1;}
b = new bla();
alert(b.a);
```

Comment: thanx, but my question is why is it so?

Comment: well thats a good question.. my guess* is because, if you don't create an instance of an object, it doesn't exist yet and therefor can't be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use a function in that manner, you're effectively making an object with a property, and you cannot access a property of an object without instantiating the object with the `new` keyword.

You could do this, which would also return 1:

```
function bla(){ return 1;}
alert (bla());
```

Answer (score 0):

What has not been pointed out is that in the case:

```
function bla(){this.a = 1}
alert (bla.a)
```

*bla* has not been called as a constructor nor as as a method of an object so its *this* keyword is set to the global/window object. Hence an *a* property is added to the global/window object and you can do:

```
alert(a)
```

but that is usually an undesirable result. In ES5 strict mode, calling a function this way will cause its *this* keyword to be *undefined*, so `this.a` will throw an error.